# Apache 24 with openldap fail to prompt user login

Tags: ldap, authentication

freeBSD 11.3, apache 24 with mod_ldap, mod_authz_ldap loaded in http.conf

here is the configuration for ldap in http.conf

```
LDAPSharedCacheSize 200000
LDAPCacheEntries 1024
LDAPCacheTTL 600
LDAPOpCacheEntries 1024
LDAPOpCacheTTL 600

LDAPTrustedGlobalCert CA_BASE64 /usr/local/etc/CA.pem
LDAPTrustedMode SSL

< Directory />
    AuthLDAPURL ldaps://ldap.jackyu.org/dc=jackyu,dc=org?uid
    AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
    AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
    AuthLDAPBindDN cn=pamclient,ou=SystemAdmin,dc=jackyu,dc=org
    AuthLDAPBindPassword xyz
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "Secure Access"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    require ldap-group cn=family,ou=group,dc=jackyu,dc=org
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
#    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on (this is removed in apache 24)
< /Directory>
```

For apapche 22, this configuration works fine, but for apache 24, when user tries to access the site, it shows forbidden (403 error), without prompting user the login popup. User has no chance to login.

This apache 24 server can connect to ldap server in the shell for user authentication. The problem is apache 24 doesn't prompt user login when user tries to access the site.

Comment: I think that this happens because  in Apache 2.4 the directives Order deny, allow.... don't work as expected. Please check official documentation for this - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html

Comment: that page doesn't explain how to control authentication by user login.

what I am looking for:

 #1 user comes to the site

 #2 show a popup for user to login (which authenticates against LDAP)

 #3 login success, grant access

 #4 login fail, deny access

Answer (score 0):

here are the configuration works for apache 24

```
LDAPSharedCacheSize 200000
LDAPCacheEntries 1024
LDAPCacheTTL 600
LDAPOpCacheEntries 1024
LDAPOpCacheTTL 600

LDAPTrustedGlobalCert CA_BASE64 /usr/local/etc/CA.pem
LDAPTrustedMode SSL

< Directory />
    AuthLDAPURL ldaps://ldap.jackyu.org/dc=jackyu,dc=org?uid
    AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
    AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
    AuthLDAPBindDN cn=pamclient,ou=SystemAdmin,dc=jackyu,dc=org
    AuthLDAPBindPassword xyz
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "Secure Access"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    Require ldap-group cn=family,ou=group,dc=jackyu,dc=org
    AllowOverride None
#    Order deny,allow (this is removed in apache 24)
#    Deny from all (this is removed in apache 24)
#    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on (this is removed in apache 24)
< /Directory>
```